# Java UDP Server not receiving packet when the byte value is positive. Works fine on localhost, but not on external IP server

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, voip

Server code

```
class UDPServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception       
    {          
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        while(true)                {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: ");
            sendData = receivePacket.getData();

            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = 
                    new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }       
    } 
}
```

and client

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Log;

public class AudioCall {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioCall";
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000; // Hertz
    private static final int SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 20; // Milliseconds
    private static final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2; // Bytes
    private static final int BUF_SIZE = SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_INTERVAL * SAMPLE_SIZE * 2; //Bytes
    private InetAddress address; // Address to call
    private int port = 9876; // Port the packets are addressed to
    private boolean mic = false; // Enable mic?
    private boolean speakers = false; // Enable speakers?

    public AudioCall(InetAddress address) {

        this.address = address;
    }

    public void startCall() {

        startMic();
        startSpeakers();
    }

    public void endCall() {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Ending call!");
        muteMic();
        muteSpeakers();
    }

    public void muteMic() {

        mic = false;
    }

    public void muteSpeakers() {

        speakers = false;
    }

    public void startMic() {
        // Creates the thread for capturing and transmitting audio
        mic = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create an instance of the AudioRecord class
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Send thread started. Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                int a = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*10;
                System.out.println("test: " + a);
                AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                        AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*10);
                int bytes_read = 0;
                int bytes_sent = 0;
                //byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE]; // 1600
                //byte buf[BUF_SIZE] = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
                try {
                    // Create a socket and start recording
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Packet destination: " + address.toString());
                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    audioRecorder.startRecording();
                    System.out.println("We can send now: " + mic);
                    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                    while(mic) {

                        // #############


                        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("212.109.192.201");
                        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                        bytes_read =  audioRecorder.read(sendData, 0, 1024);
                        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
                        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                        // ##############



                        // Capture audio from the mic and transmit it
                        //bytes_read = audioRecorder.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
                        //audioRecorder.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);

//                        byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
//                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, 1024, IPAddress, 9876);
                        //DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, bytes_read, address, port);
//                        socket.send(packet);
                        bytes_sent += bytes_read;
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Total bytes sent: " + bytes_sent);
                       // Thread.sleep(SAMPLE_INTERVAL, 0);
                    }
                    // Stop recording and release resources
                    audioRecorder.stop();
                    audioRecorder.release();
                    socket.disconnect();
                    socket.close();
                    mic = false;
                    return;
                }
//                catch(InterruptedException e) {
//
//                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
//                    mic = false;
//                }
                catch(SocketException e) {

                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SocketException: " + e.toString());
                    mic = false;
                }
                catch(UnknownHostException e) {

                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString());
                    mic = false;
                }
                catch(IOException e) {

                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
                    mic = false;
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public void startSpeakers() {
        // Creates the thread for receiving and playing back audio
        if(!speakers) {

            speakers = true;
            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Create an instance of AudioTrack, used for playing back audio
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Receive thread started. Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUF_SIZE, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                    track.play();
                    try {
                        // Define a socket to receive the audio
                        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                        byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
                        System.out.println("We can listen now: " + speakers);
                        while(speakers) {
                            // Play back the audio received from packets
                            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, BUF_SIZE);
                            socket.receive(packet);
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Packet received: " + packet.getLength());
                            track.write(packet.getData(), 0, BUF_SIZE);
                        }
                        // Stop playing back and release resources
                        socket.disconnect();
                        socket.close();
                        track.stop();
                        track.flush();
                        track.release();
                        speakers = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    catch(SocketException e) {

                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SocketException: " + e.toString());
                        speakers = false;
                    }
                    catch(IOException e) {

                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
                        speakers = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            receiveThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine on localhost, but UDP server doesn't receive on public server, and in some cases it only receives first 4 packets then stops. Server os is ubuntu 14.0 version, no firewall. I have noticed that it receives UDP packets when their bytes have negative value, but do not when it is positive. Everything is fine with android manifest, it has internet and other required permissions. I want to create an app where it creates like a channel, and broadcasts audio to that channel. And any client can listen audio by listening to particular channel. The problem is that it should be real time and have a seek function, so while you are listening real time and can go back to listen for few seconds before or even start to listen from the beginning. Any suggestions please? I would be very grateful for your response

Comment: The situation you describe is impossible. UDP datagrams are received entire and intact or not at all, and UDP doesn't care about the sign of payload bytes. You need to post your actual and expected outputs. There are already problems with the code you've posted beyond what can be noted in a comment. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe is impossible as noted in comments. However this:

```
while(true)
{
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
    System.out.println("RECEIVED: ");
    sendData = receivePacket.getData();

    InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
    int port = receivePacket.getPort();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = 
        new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
    serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
}
```

is not correct. You are always replying with 1024 bytes regardless of what was actually received. And as the received packet already contains its own length and source address, it can all be simplified drastically to this:

```
while(true)
{
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
    System.out.println("RECEIVED: ");
    serverSocket.send(receivePacket);
}
```

In the client, you don't need to keep getting the same `InetAddress` inside the loop, and the following:

```
bytes_read =  audioRecorder.read(sendData, 0, 1024);
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
```

should be:

```
bytes_read =  audioRecorder.read(sendData, 0, 1024);
if (bytesRead == -1)
    break;
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, bytesRead, IPAddress, 9876);
```